# Creating category-subcategory model upto nth level in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to create a model of categories with nth level subcategories. I can create upto 2 levels but could not go beyond it.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
   belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"
end
```

I do not want to use any gem for it.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit i would try this

```
#category.rb
has_many :sub_category_ones
has_many :sub_category_twos, through: :sub_category_ones
has_many :sub_category_threes, through: :sub_category_twos
has_many :sub_category_fours, through: :sub_category_threes

#sub_category_one.rb
belongs_to :category
has_many :sub_category_twos

#sub_category_two.rb
belongs_to :sub_category_one
has_many :sub_category_threes

#sub_category_three.rb
belongs_to :sub_category_two
has_many :sub_category_fours

#sub_category_fours
belongs_to :sub_category_three
```

And then you can say:

`category.sub_category_fours # I think! :)`

Will you please send me the strong-params if it works and you build a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` corresponding system, so you can save it all with @category.save!

Good luck! I hope it works. :)

Comment: I just need to go upto 3-4 levels.